# Can the Desktop directory be a symbolic link in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, dropbox, symbolic-link

I would like to synchronize the Desktop directory between computers. On Linux i could just move the Desktop directory to my Dropbox directory, and then create a symlink from the old location to the new one. Will this work in Windows 10? Should I create a soft symlink or a directory junction? Are there easier ways to synchronize the Desktop directory between computers?

Comment: You can create directory junction using **mklink /j**  and that should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 has built in support for changing the desktop location.

1. In File Explorer, Right-click the Desktop folder under **Quick Access** and click **Properties**.
2. Switch to the **Location** tab, and click the **Move** button.
3. Open up the folder you want to use, (in your case the Dropbox folder), click **Select Folder**, and **Apply** your changes.
4. If you see a dialog asking “Do you want to move all of the files from the old location to the new location?”, click **Yes** to move all files to the new location.

If everything is done correctly, your desktop should display the contents of your selected folder.

[Source: Into Windows](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-move-desktop-downloads-documents-to-another-drive-in-windows-10/)